# Lucene Configuration for Different Languages

Tags: lucene

I am interrested in learning how lucene configures for different languages. Is there any way to know how the tokenizer is configured and what characters are considered to be part of words and which dont?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is not configured by default to handle languages. It is rather up to you, my advice would be to index several languages in different Document fields, each for a language, and use the proper Analyzers each time.

So Lucene has no default configuration for this, but if you're using Elasticsearch or Solr, there may be. Are you using Lucene out of the box ?

Regards,

Comment: I am using lucene but the work at hand is for compressing strings. Since one can do about 100million characters per second and core and Java requires 2 bytes per char or using UTF-8 also is in that range, compressing those Strings in memory fits quite nicely. You get 1:3 to 1:4 out of it and with he the two bytes you are 1:6 to 1:8 inmemory also avoiding the String handling of Java completely (like having Strings that are actually only needed for parts to them). Also those strings must rarely be decompressed since the decompression is available at the client.

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand, you tagged this question as Lucene. What's your goal actually ?

Comment: Lucene at least Solr comes with default tokenizers for different languages. I need also write tokenizers for different languages so I want to understand how they are configured, what values and so on. It is about the configuration and algorithms they use.